# VBA code that appears only when a cell in a selected row is non blank

Tags: vba, excel, button, locking, password-protection

Here's the scenario. I would like to have a command button that only appears if  a specific cell in a row is non-blank.  I'd also like the command button to lock the entire row once clicked (by "lock it", I mean to prevent editing of the cells).

I have come across the following two codes:

**1. Worksheet code for hiding/unhiding the button:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Cells(1, 14).Value <> "" Then
        CommandButton2.Visible = True
    Else
        CommandButton2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

**2. Module code for making the button lock the cells upon clicking the button:**

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Locked = True
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.FormulaHidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

However, the challenge is that I want the button to work for every row and the locking to be for D1 to N1 only. However, having buttons of every column can potentially get messy and slow down the spreadsheet performance. So, is there a way I can use one button only (P.S. I can put the button at the top of the spreadsheet and I can freeze the top row so as to have the button always displayed no matter how much further down I am in the spreadsheet)?

I'm thinking if I'm working on row 5, per se, I can just select row 5 (by clicking on the row header, then the code can evaluate N5, then the command button appears if N5 is non-blank, then when the button is clicked, cells D5 to N5 get locked. And the same thing is for all the other rows.

Comment: how does the cell become non-blank?

Comment: @jsotola. Hi mate. The cell becomes non-blank by entering data into it. I want to lock their data entered once they click the button.

Comment: tip:  you can replace the `if ... then ... else` in worksheet_change with one line `CommandButton2.Visible = (Cells(1, 14).Value <> "")`

Comment: the `Target` in `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` is a Range object that contains a collection of all the cells that were changed when the sub was called. if you enter a value into a cell, then only that cell will be in the `Target` object, but if you paste into multiple cells, then `Target` will be a collection of cells that you pasted into. to filter out just some cells, you want to use the `intersect` method.   ..... check here http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-intersect.htm

Comment: the Worksheet_Change code would need to pass information the the button, telling it which rows to lock, if it is pressed

Comment: why do you need to use a button?  i know what it does, but why a button?  what if they forget to press it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. Install it in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want your buttons.

Look upon the Enum at the top as some kind of control panel. This is where you set parameters used throughout the code. For example, you can change the first data row from 2 to something else. I have named column D "NclTest" and column N "NclResult". Use Edit/Replace to change these names to something more appropriate. Note that enumeration names are not case sensitive. So, if you write them once in lower case my precious capitalisations will be gone forever.

I have set column O (15) to take the "button". This you must change if you have other things in column O. Assign a column which is empty.

Now, when you activate the sheet all items in column N will be checked and "buttons" created in column O. After that updates will be made whenever there is a change. Therefore it isn't necessary more than once. But bear in mind that the updating doesn't work on more than one cell. So, if you copy/paste bigger ranges deactivate and reactivate the worksheet to update the buttons.

```
Option Explicit

    Const Pw As String = "password"

Private Enum Ncl                ' worksheet columns
    ' 11 Aug 2017
    NclFirstDataRow = 2         ' change as appropriate
    NclTest = 4                 ' 4 = D (used to test if range is locked)
    NclResult = 14              ' 14 = N
    NclButton = 15              ' = column O (change as required)
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 29 Aug 2017

    Dim TestVal
    Dim Cap As String
    Dim Rl As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NclResult).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = NclFirstDataRow To Rl
            ResetButton R
        Next R

        ' you can double-click this cell to end Administrator rights
        .Cells(1, NclButton).Locked = False

        .Protect Password:="", _
                 DrawingObjects:=True, _
                 Contents:=True, _
                 Scenarios:=True, _
                 UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 29 Aug 2017

    Dim LockStatus As Boolean

    Set Target = Target.Cells(1)        ' only accept first cell
                                        ' meaning you can't copy/paste ranges

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, WsRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Locked Then
            MsgBox "This cell is locked for editing", _
                   vbInformation, "Modification not allowed"

            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' reset the button when Result is changed
    If Application.Intersect(Target, WsRange(C:=NclResult)) Is Nothing Then
        ' reset range lock when button is changed
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, WsRange(C:=NclButton)) Is Nothing Then
            With Target
                If Len(Trim(.Value)) Then
                    LockStatus = (.Value = BtnCap(1))
                    WsRange(.Row).Locked = LockStatus
                Else
                    ResetButton .Row
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Else
        ResetButton Target.Row
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 29 Aug 2017

    Static PermitEdit As Boolean
    Dim Cap As String

    Set Target = Target.Cells(1)        ' only accept first cell
                                        ' meaning you can't copy/paste ranges
    If Target.Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, NclButton).Address Then
        If PermitEdit Then
            PermitEdit = False
            MsgBox "Administrator rights have been terminated.", _
                   vbInformation, "End of Admin session"
        End If
    Else
        If Not Intersect(Target, WsRange(C:=NclButton)) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Target
                Do While Not PermitEdit
                    If RefuseAccess(PermitEdit) Then GoTo AccessDenied
                Loop
                Cap = Trim(.Value)
                If Len(Cap) Then
                    .Value = BtnCap(Int(Cap = BtnCap(1)) + 1)
                End If
                .Offset(0, -1).Select
            End With
AccessDenied:
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function RefuseAccess(PermitEdit As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' 29 Aug 2017

    Dim Pass As String
    Dim Rl As Long

    Pass = InputBox("Please enter the administrator's password", _
                    "Password required")
    PermitEdit = Not CBool(StrComp(Pass, Pw, vbBinaryCompare))
    If PermitEdit Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NclResult).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(NclFirstDataRow, NclButton - 1), .Cells(Rl, NclButton)).Locked = False
        End With
    Else
        If Len(Pass) Then
            MsgBox "The password is not correct." & vbCr & _
                   "Access will be denied.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid password"
        End If
    End If
    RefuseAccess = Not PermitEdit
End Function

Private Function BtnCap(ByVal CapId As Long) As String
    ' 11 Aug 2017
    BtnCap = Split("LOCK,UNLOCK", ",")(CapId)
End Function

Private Function WsRange(Optional R As Long, _
                         Optional C As Long) As Range
    ' 11 Aug 2017

    Dim Rstart As Long, Rend As Long
    Dim Cstart As Long, Cend As Long

    If R Then
        Rstart = R
        Rend = R
    Else
        Rstart = NclFirstDataRow
        Rend = Cells(Rows.Count, NclResult).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    If C Then
        Cstart = C
        Cend = C
    Else
        Cstart = NclTest
        Cend = NclResult
    End If

    Set WsRange = Range(Cells(Rstart, Cstart), Cells(Rend, Cend))
End Function

Private Sub ResetButton(ByVal R As Long)
    ' 11 Aug 2017

    Dim TestVal
    Dim Cap As String

    With Cells(R, NclResult)
        TestVal = .Value
        If Len(TestVal) Then
            Cap = ""
        Else
            ' if NclTest is locked then D:N are presumed locked
            Cap = BtnCap(Int(Cells(R, NclTest).Locked) + 1)
        End If
    End With

    With Cells(R, NclButton)
        If .Value <> Cap Then
            .Value = Cap
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

There are no buttons. It's just the cells in column O which are marked "LOCK" or "UNLOCK". While column N isn't empty column O will be blank. If N is blank O will have a button which toggles on click. You can't click twice in a row without clicking elsewhere in between. That's Excel, not me. You can press Delete to toggle as often as you wish.

When the "button" says "Lock" the cells D:N are unlocked and can be edited. If you edit N the button may disappear. If the button is "UNLOCK" the cells are locked and you get a message when you try to edit them after which the edit is reversed. You guessed correctly: I don't like worksheet protection.

It would be easy to format the "buttons" a little bit, either using code or just format column O. With similar ease you could highlight the locked cells. I didn't want to do it all. So I left the best part of the fun to you. :-)

Comment: Hi. I'm so sorry for the late reply. I saw your message on the first day you posted the answer above, but I couldn't get it to work on that day as it was debugging, then I got distracted with the fact that we need to put the spreadsheet online so we can all coauthor it. I'm sure I must have entered something wrong while entering your code. I'll check it again soon. Thanks again!!

Comment: Thank you for your courtesy. I tested this code on my PC. So I am rather confident that it should work for you too. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks again for all your hard work. What you did with that code is mind blowing. I'm afraid I wasn't very clear. I'd like to keep the unlock option only for an admin. I am setting this up to prevent changes. Or is there a way we can accomplish this without buttons, say when the user saves the workbook, all what he entered in that session gets locked. But the trick is I need an admin person who have access to unlocking it and making changes

Comment: As I said, I don't like worksheet protection. But now I have added it to the code which makes the whole thing a little chequered. You now need a password to operate the buttons. Click "Lock" or "Unlock" to be prompted for the password in the `Pw` constant at the top of the code. You can continue locking and unlocking after that. If you click in the cell in row 1 of the column in which the buttons are the access permission will be revoked.

Comment: Interesting. I realised that the user can forget to Lock.
I came across this however 
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/686259-auto-lock-cells-after-data-entry-when-file-saved.html
What do you think? I have raised a question somewhere else to try to combine my code with the code in the link above. I'll tag you there maybe you can help as we can't ask more than one question in one page. Is that ok?

Comment: I tagged you in the new thread by putting @ before your name. Will that work?

Comment: It will work better if you mark my previous efforts as helpful. I don't know if it is worth being marked as an "answer", but it must be more than nothing.